# Enabling bokeh y (x) axis ticks on both left and right (top and bottom)

Tags: python, bokeh

How can I activate bokeh axis ticks (not necessarily the tick labels nor the axis label, although that may be helpful too) on both sides of a plot simultaneously?

For reference, in [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params.html) I would set `tick_params` (e.g. `bottom`, `top` and `left`, `right`) all to `True`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `axis_location` parameter to `figure` is a convenience for the common case of adding one axis. Multiple axes can always be added explicitly using `Plot.add_layout` e.g.

```
 plot.add_layout(LinearAxis(), 'left')
 plot.add_layout(LinearAxis(), 'right')
```

There is an extreme example that exercises the addition of many axes and titles here:

https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/models/file/panels.py

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping for something I would be able to set through a `Theme`. So your reply probably means it is not that easy yet. Adding an axis the way you suggest does involve, if I understand correctly, indexing into the specific layout, then retrieving axis names of the one you'd want to 'mirror', so it may be harder to automate.

Comment: Exposing as a theme might be difficult, but we could probably add new values that `xaxis_location` understands, to add both sides. Feel free to open a GH issue to discuss

Answer (score -1):

As far as I can tell, for fixed lines you do:

```
p.xaxis.ticker = [2, 3.5, 4]
```

Here is a link with many more examples, in order to achieve the exact thing you are after, [ticker examples](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/styling.html#fixedticker) . Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That only seems to change the locations of the ticks and does not 'mirror' those ticks onto the upper boundary of the plot, though.